# Import-PFXCertificate: The specified network password is not correct

Tags: powershell, azure

I've got some pretty simple code I'm trying to troubleshoot. The environment is an Azure Windows Server 2012 machine, and I'm logged in as a domain admin running a Powershell console with Administrator privileges.

I'm just trying to Import-PFXCertificate from a known location but it will not accept the network password.

Here's the code.

```
$SecurePWD = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'iW@nt2die' -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PFXCertificate -Password $SecurePWD -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root" -FilePath "C:\Certs\TestCert.pfx"
```

When I run this beautiful block of code, with the password being absolutely correct (I tested by logging in using the password), it greets me with this error:

```
Import-PFXCertificate : The specified network password is not correct.
```

WHYYYY.

I've tried escaping out the @, but that doesn't do anything. I've tried crying, but the computer is completely unmoved by my tears.

Comment: Isn't that the password of the PDX cert and not the password for an account? I don't understand how you logged in with it.

Comment: Oh, am I just completely misunderstanding the password switch? It's saying "Network password is not correct" so I assumed it meant... y'know, my network password.

Comment: Probably. If the cert doesn't have a password I would try it blank

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue and it only occurs on Server versions of Windows and I don't even have a password on my cert! Microsoft absolutely sucks when it comes bubbling up the actual errors and you end wasting hours and hours getting no where as I am now. And as usual it'll be some stupid security setting I have to override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per documentation for [Import-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps), the `-Password` parameter is for the password of the certificate and not the user to login with.

> -Password - Specifies the password for the imported PFX file in the form of a secure string.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a little older, but as I saw that some people commented recently, i wanted to share our solution.

We had a similar problem when we tried to replace our SSL certificate by a new one.
We experienced the same error message but while using the method `Get-PfxData`, not `Import-Pfx` but I think it's the same issue.

The problem was that our new Pfx-Password contained a dollar sign `$` which is reserved in Powershell to be variable. After escaping the dollar sign with a quote (`) it worked.

So if the password was XyZaBc$DeF we needed to use XyZaBc`$DeF.

That solved the problem in our case.